# Python regex does not recognise text

Tags: python, python-re

I wrote a regex that should recognise `string: number`.
I do not get any errors but I get only `string:` without `number`

There a couple of variations of word that should represent string and number should be integer from 7 do 9 digits.

```
import re


text = 'Center Postfach 2250 Kundennummer: 90289963 CH-4002 Basel Frau Re'

regex = r"(kundennummer|kundennummer.|kundennummer:|numéro d'abonné||Kunden Nr.|No de client:)\s\d{7,9}"


gpnumber_list = re.findall(regex, text, re.IGNORECASE)
print(gpnumber_list) #['Kundennummer:']
```

Expected result:

```
Kundennummer: 90289963
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another capturing group for the number.

```
regex = r"(kundennummer|kundennummer.|kundennummer:|numéro d'abonné||Kunden Nr.|No de client:)\s(\d{7,9})"
```

Notice parentheses around `\d{7,9}`.

---

To get a list of strings, as pointed out in the comment, you can simply join the matched groups

```
[" ".join(item) for item in gpnumber_list]
```

Comment: It works but it returns tuple inside of the list, is there a way to return string in list?

Comment: You mean like `"Kundennummer: 90289963"`?